# Q-Qplot with outliers on the same side?

Tags: r, qq-plot

What does it mean when there are outliers in a Q-Q plot on the same side of the plot at both ends of the tails? I've attached the example I have, which is showing the residuals for the abundance of my sample of study.

[image: Output Q-Q plot with fitted line from R]

Comment: Your distribution is negatively skewed relative to the normal. To get a fuller sense of the shape, make a density plot & look at descriptive statistics as well.

Comment: Do you know what that would mean for the normality of my data? Can I say it's normal? I have also plotted a histogram, but I'm not sure how to do a density plot. I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: @morecoffeeplz you can plot the density like this `plot(density(mydata))`, it will show you the actual distribution of your data.

Comment: Without knowing more about your situation, your data, & your goals, there isn't much more that can be said.

Comment: Ordinarily few or none of the points on this plot would be called "outliers"--certainly none of those in the lower tail.  The points in this plot simply don't follow the reference line you have drawn, that's all.